# Есть ли возможность привязать к демону DHCP событие, которое срабатывало при освобождении ip адреса?

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

На текущий момент, нашел информацию только про лог файл демона dhcp.leases

Посоветуете методы решения.
Так как считаю постоянно мониторить файл неправильно.

Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: [dhcp-клиент не обязан посылать запрос на освобождение адреса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_releasing). да и, частенько, просто не в состоянии этого сделать. опираться на подобные запросы — мне кажется, не стоит.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/436943/how-to-run-a-script-when-there-is-a-change-in-your-local-ip